# testing an angular service without an application

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test, angular-library

I have only one .ts file (not angular project) containing a single service

it is just one file, not a complete angular project, and it is even not an angular library (doesn't contain angular.json at all)

I can import this service to any angular application and it works fine.
I want to add a test file beside it, and then run this  test via jest as a single file, i.e not inside an angular application

I use `TestBed` but I always got `getComponentFromError`

how can I run the test without a complete angular project (app or lib)

Comment: You can use Jest : https://jestjs.io/

Answer (score 1):

`TestBed` would ensure the usage of Angular dependency injection and `ngZone`. If you don't need those for the service under the test, you can instantiate the service using the constructor and proceed as with any other Angular tests.

```js
const sut: MyClass;
beforeEach(() => {
   sut = new MyClass();
})
if(`kill all humans when time has come`, () => {
   const doomsDay = new Date(year, month, day);
   sut.killAllHumanWhenTimeHasCome(doomsDay);
})
```

If you also don't have a test runner and assertion engine, you might just add jasmine as it is described in [the getting started instruction](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html).